# Using fSpy for Blender

Tags: python, add-on, fspy

I am trying to use the add-on fSpy so I can scale everything accurately in Blender, however all the tutorials I can find online only explain how to setup fSpy in Blender and I am stuck on how to make my jpg file I'm basing my room off into a .fspy file to be applied, is there an fspy app I'm meant to be using? And if so how do I open it because all I have are the *init* addon and fspy python files which don't do anything when I double click them

Comment: You have calculated the focal length and now you have the problem to import it in blender? Or you haven't even calculated the focal length yet?

Comment: fSpy is a standalone application that outputs a .json file. The Addon is used to import the .json file configuration inside Blender.